# limitation on writing line to .csv or .txt file php

Tags: php, file

i wrote a convert bulk data from an excel to a .txt or .csv by using fwrite php. however when I fread on the .txt file that my data placed on, the data turned out broken line. how can i fix it? Attached here is the highlighted from .txt or .csv and also the codes as below:-

**********my write code *************

```
for loop here {
    $split_filename_path = fopen($tempfile_path.$split_filename.$total_round.$extension, "w");`
    $split_file_txt = $ISBN.$comma.$Title.$comma.$Qty.$comma.$Location.$comma.$outlet;
    fwrite($split_filename_path, $split_file_txt);
}
fclose($split_filename_path);
```

then it comes here
**********my read code***************

```
    $myfile = fopen($file, "r");
    $fread = fread($myfile,filesize($file));
        
    fclose($myfile);
    $split = explode("\n",$fread);
    $datafields = array('ISBN', 'title', 'qty', 'location', 'outlet');
    $insertvalues = array();
    foreach($split as $string){ 
        $row = explode(",",$string);
        $questionmarks[] = '(' . $this->placeholder('?',$irow, sizeof($row)) . ')'; 
        $insertvalues = array_merge( $insertvalues, array_values($row));
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_data (".implode( ',', $datafields) . ") 
                VALUES ". implode( ',', $questionmarks);
    
    function placeholder( $text, $irow, $count = 0, $separator = ',' ) {
        $result = array();
        if ($count > 0) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
                $result[] = $text;
            }
        }
        return implode($separator, $result);
    }
```

with this codes, the result that I have is here :

```
9780794435295,BARBIE & HER SISTERS IN THE GREAT PUPPY ADVENTURE: (supposed to be full :- BARBIE & HER SISTERS IN THE GREAT PUPPY ADVENTURE: A SLIDING TAB BOOK BARBIE MOVIE TIEIN )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found the answer.
$Title = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $Title);